Kafka installation issue while installing Scorpio broker using docker compose
I am trying to install scorpio broker on a Ubuntu machine. Scorpio broker requires supporting applications like Kafka and postgres.
I tried to use the docker compose files provided in the GitHub for scorpio documentation.
I am facing errors like below.
scorpio    | 2024-12-23 12:27:46,192 WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.ClientUtils] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0) Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka
scorpio    | 2024-12-23 12:27:46,198 ERROR [io.sma.rea.mes.provider] (main) SRMSG00230: Unable to create the publisher or subscriber during initialization: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
scorpio    |    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.<init>(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:264)
scorpio    |    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerDelegateCreator.create(ConsumerDelegateCreator.java:65)
scorpio    |    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:600)
scorpio    |    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:595)
scorpio    |    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.impl.ReactiveKafkaConsumer.lambda$new$0(ReactiveKafkaConsumer.java:124)
scorpio    |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference.updateAndGet(AtomicReference.java:210)
scorpio    |    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.impl.ReactiveKafkaConsumer.lambda$new$1(ReactiveKafkaConsumer.java:120)
scorpio    |    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualSupplier.get(SlowContextualSupplier.java:21)
scorpio    |    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromItemSupplier.subscribe(UniCreateFromItemSupplier.java:28)
scorpio    |    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
scorpio    |    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.withSubscriber(UniSubscribe.java:51)
scorpio    |    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniMemoizeOp.subscribe(UniMemoizeOp.java:59)
scorpio    |    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
scorpio    |    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniRunSubscribeOn.lambda$subscribe$0(UniRunSubscribeOn.java:27)
scorpio    |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
scorpio    |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
scorpio    |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
scorpio    |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
scorpio    |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
scorpio    |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
scorpio    | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
scorpio    |    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:103)
scorpio    |    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:62)
scorpio    |    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:58)
scorpio    |    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.<init>(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:183)

Docker file used : Docker compose file
Content:
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181"
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.5.1-debian-11-r6
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS: 10000
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS: 5000
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis
    ports:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ngb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ngb
      POSTGRES_DB: ngb
  scorpio:
    image: scorpiobroker/all-in-one-runner:java-kafka-latest
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    environment:
      DBHOST: postgres
      BUSHOST: kafka
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - kafka


From logs looks like smallrye requires kafka broker to be provided

I am not sure about this smallrye, is there anything I can do to fix this. Please note I have no idea pretty much about Kafka.   It was just a component required for scorpio installation.
